# sorting a linked list containing strings

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, mergesort, qsort

So what I want to do is to sort an linked list containing only strings. To do so, I have 2 options.

Option 1 - dynamically allocate an array with the same size as the linked list and the strings containing it also with the same size, copy the contents of the linked list into the array and sort it using `qsort`.

Option 2 - implement a merge sort algorithm in order to sort it.

One of the problems is will it cost more memory and time if I do option 2 over option 1 or the option is the better?

My second problem is that I'm trying to do option 1 and to do so I have a header file which contains the code of the linked lists.
The problem is after allocating memory for the array of strings when I try to copy the contents I get segmentation fault.

Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Listas_ligadas_char.h"

int main() {
    link_char head = NULL;
    char **strings;
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "fcb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "bvb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "slb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "fcp");
    int len = length_char(head);
    int i = 0, j;
    strings = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * len);
    link_char t;
    t = head;
    while (t != NULL && i <= len) {
        strings[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(t->str) + 1));
        strcpy(strings[i++], t->v.str)
        t = t->next;
    }
    for (t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
        printf("* %s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef _Listas_ligadas_char_
#define _Listas_ligadas_char_

#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_char {
    char *str;
    struct node_char *next;
} *link_char;

link_char lookup_str(link_char head, char *str) {
    link_char t;
    for (t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next)
        if (strcmp(t->str, str) == 0)
            return t;
    return NULL;
}

link_char NEW_str(char *str) {
    int i;
    link_char x = (link_char)malloc(sizeof(struct node_char));
    x->str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    strcpy(x->str, str);
    x->next = NULL;
    return x;
}

link_char insertEnd_char(link_char head, char *str) {
    link_char x;
    if (head == NULL)
        return NEW_str(str);
    for (x = head; x->next != NULL; x = x->next)
        ;
    x->next = NEW_str(str);
    return head;
}

int length_char(link_char head) {
    int count = 0;
    link_char x;
    for (x = head; x != NULL; x = x->next)
        count++;
    return count;
}

void print_lista_char(link_char head, int NL) {
    link_char t;
    for (t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
        printf("%d * %s\n", NL, t->str);
    }
}

void FREEnode_str(link_char t) {
    free(t->str);
    free(t);
}

link_char delete_el_char(link_char head, char *str) {
    link_char t, prev;
    for (t = head, prev = NULL; t != NULL;
        prev = t, t = t->next) {
        if (strcmp(t->str, str) == 0) {
            if (t == head)
                head = t->next;
            else
                prev->next = t->next;
            FREEnode_str(t);
            break;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
#endif
```

btw if you are wondering what `NL` is, `NL` is a variable to count the respective line of the `stdin` and what I only want is to print the array, I don't want to keep its elements.

So if you can tell what option you think is the best I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: A header file should not normally contain function definitions (or variable definitions).  It should only contain declarations. If a header does contain function definitions, they should normally be `static inline` functions.  Otherwise, you can't use the header in more than one file in any program, which defeats the purpose of have a header in the first place.

Comment: Sure but the header file isnt the problem, the problem is in the main function, the header is just to see the implementation of the linked list

Comment: @MartimCorreia: It is generally a good idea to not put all your code into a single file, but to order it into several files. However, it would have been more appropriate to create another `.c` file for the function definitions of the linked list and to create an `.h` file for the declarations (which is then included by all `.c` files).

Answer (score 1):

> Option 1 - dynamically allocate an array with the same size as the linked list and the strings containing it also with the same size, copy the contents of the linked list into the array and sort it using qsort.

It is not necessary to convert the linked list to an array. The [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm can also be applied to linked lists.

However, since your linked list is only [singly-linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list), you cannot use the (generally more efficient) [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), but must use the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) instead. This is because the Hoare partition scheme requires the ability to traverse the linked list backwards (which requires a [doubly-linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly_linked_list) list).

Even if it is not necessary to convert the linked list to an array for the quicksort algorithm, this may still be meaningful, as a linked list has worse [spacial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) than an array. Either way, the average [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of the algorithm will be O(n*log n) and the worst-case time complexity will be O(n^2).

But since your nodes only contain pointers to strings, you will have bad spacial locality anyway when dereferencing these pointers. So in this case, it may not be very helpful to convert the linked list to an array, because that would only improve the spacial locality of the pointers to the strings, but not of the strings themselves.

---

> One of the problems is will it cost more memory and time if i do option2 over option1 or the option is the better?

[Merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is ideal for linked lists.

Another advantage of merge-sort is its worst-case time complexity, which is O(n*log n), whereas it is O(n^2) with quicksort.

Merge-sort has a [space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) of O(1) for linked lists, whereas quicksort has a space complexity of O(log n). However, if you decide to convert the list to an array for quicksort, the space complexity of your algorithm will increase to O(n) ).

---

> My second problem is that im trying to do option 1 and to do so i have an header file which contains the code of the linked lists. The problem is after allocating memory for the array of strings when i try to copy the contents i get segmentation fault.

I can only help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. The code you posted does not reproduce the problem. It does not even compile. The following line contains several errors:

`strcpy(strings[i++],t->v.str)`

Comment: Man to say i didnt try to debug the problem myself is disrespectfull, if i knew what the problem was i wouldnt be posting help ok, and actualy that was the  minimal reproducible example of my program, i just added the insert_node lines in order to people know what was inside the linked list.

Comment: *Both merge-sort and quicksort have a space complexity of O(1)*: I'm afraid I disagree: both have a space complexity of **O(log(N))**. Insertion sort has a space complexity of **O(1)**.

Comment: @chqrlie: Actually, with linked lists, merge sort has a space complexity of O(1), at least according to [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Comparison_with_other_sort_algorithms). However, you are right that quicksort has a space complexity of O(log n), so I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MartimCorreia: After reading your question again, I noticed that you did indeed provide a bit of information about where the segmentation fault was occuring. Therefore, I apologize for implying that you hadn't attempted to debug your program yourself and I have removed those comments from my answer. However, I still think that it would have been better if you had provided more detailed debugging information, for example by specifying exactly in what line the segmentation fault is occuring.

Comment: well ive just fixed it thanks man i was forgetting to initialize the strings of the well to simplify the work i used calloc instead of malloc, but my problem now is the sorting part

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: the reason the article mentions O(1) is most merge sort algorithm make an assumption about the maximum value of N for practical purposes and use a fixed structure whose size is proportional to O(log(MAXN)). For example a typical top-down implementation of mergesort on lists will use an array of 32 entries to handle lists of up to 8 billion elements. The size of this array should really be log2(length(list)) give or take 1, but it is more practical to make it a fixed size of 32.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have 2 sensible options:

- option 1 will usually provide the best performance but requires additional space of `sizeof(link_char) * N`.
- option 2 will only require **O(log(N))** stack space for pending sublists using bottom-up mergesort or similar space complexity for recursive top-down mergesort. The drawback is you have to write the sorting function yourself and it is easy to make mistakes.

Note that for option 1, you should not make a copy of the strings, but just allocate an array of pointers and initialize it to point to the nodes themselves. This way you can preserve the node structures that could contain other information and avoid extra allocations.

Note also that once you have the array of node pointers and a comparison function, you can use `qsort` or other sorting functions such as `timsort` or `mergesort` which may be more appropriate in terms of worst case time complexity.

There are multiple problems in your implementation:

- the loop test `while (t != NULL && i <= len)` is incorrect. the tests should be redundant, but if you insist on testing `i`, it should be `i < len` or you might access beyond the end of the `string` array if `length_char` returned an incorrect count.
- `strcpy(strings[i++], t->v.str)` has a syntax error, you probably mean `strcpy(strings[i++], t->str);`
- the printing loop has undefined behavior because you do not reset `i` to `0` nor do you increment `i` in the loop body, so you pass `strings[i]` for all calls to `printf` and `i` should be `len`, so `strings[i]` accesses beyond the end of the allocated array. You might get a crash or an invalid pointer or by chance a null pointer that `printf` might ignore... It should be:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("* %s\n", strings[i]);
  }
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Listas_ligadas_char.h"

int cmp_char(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    link_char a = *(const link_char *)aa;
    link_char b = *(const link_char *)bb;
    return strcmp(a->str, b->str);
}

link_char sort_char(link_char head) {
    if (head != NULL && head->next != NULL) {
        size_t i, len = length_char(head);
        link_char *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * len);
        link_char t = head;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++, t = t->next)
            array[i] = t;
        qsort(array, len, sizeof(*array), cmp_char);
        head = t = array[0];
        for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
            t = t->next = array[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        free(array);
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    link_char head = NULL;

    head = insertEnd_char(head, "fcb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "bvb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "slb");
    head = insertEnd_char(head, "fcp");

    head = sort_char(head);

    for (link_char t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
        printf("* %s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- it is error prone to hide pointers behind typedefs. You should define `node_char` as `typedef struct node_char node_char` and use `node_char *` everywhere.
- it is unconventional to define the list functions in the header file. You might do this for `static inline` functions, but the global functions should not be defined in the header file as this will cause name clashes if multiple modules include this header file and get linked together.

Comment: ok i inicitlized the array of pointers the problems is that when i try to use strcpy() to copy the contents i doesnt copy anything and if i try to print the array it prints NULL.

Comment: @MartimCorreia: I amended the answer with an analysis of problems in your implementation which might explain your observations.